# How To Add Video To 3D Cube via HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, 3d

im trying to replace a 3D cube with images with video to add on each face, I'm having problems trying to figure out how to replace the html tag with a html video element tag..

My jsfiddle can be seen below

http://jsfiddle.net/sean3200/W4pGa/

Here's the beginning of the code where the image is being created...

```
      function start3d(texture_image) {
       var screen_canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
```

Here is the bottom of my code where the image is being loaded

```
      var img = new Image();
      img.onload = function() { start3d(img); };
      img.src = 'http://content.bitsontherun.com/thumbs/3XnJSIm4-640.jpg';</script>
```

I know on how to create and load a video via html5 but puting it on each cube is a bit different.. any help on this would be appreciated!! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put this code inside your div

```
<object width="400" height="400"><param name="movie"    value="http://www.youtube.com/v/YLorLVa95Xo?fs=1&amp;hl=en_GB&amp;rel=0"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/YLorLVa95Xo?fs=1&amp;hl=en_GB&amp;rel=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="400" height="400"></embed></object>
```

or use javascript to set videeo on second div of cube class if you have it in html body:

```
$('.cube > div').eq(1).html('<object width="360" height="360"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/YLorLVa95Xo?fs=1&amp;hl=en_GB&amp;rel=0"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/YLorLVa95Xo?fs=1&amp;hl=en_GB&amp;rel=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="360" height="360"></embed></object>');
```

It is working fine in chrome, If it works in safari and firefox, please reply back.